# Existing Angular 2 project needs data from sql server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a small Angular 2 application, but I can't find a way to connect and send queries to an existing sql server. 
I found that I need to build a rest API and that I can use 'express.js'. 
I also found that express.js can run my Angular 2 app at the same time as the backend server, but how do I set this up? 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Edit:

I'm still stuck, can anyone point me to a tutorial or something I can use to build an Angular 2 app that can send sql queries to a Microsoft SQL server and use this data in its templates?

Edit 2:

I used the Node package MSSQL to do this. Pretty easy when you get it set up. 
[MSSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into setting up a SEAN stack application that would use Sequelize ORM to read from your SQL database.

https://github.com/MangoTools/sean

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/

Comment: Isn't SEAN stack only for AngularJs and not Angular 2?

Comment: It's the same concept but sub out AngularJS for Angular2

Comment: Is it possible to create queries with user input and send the query to the API to get the correct sql data with Sequelize?

Comment: If you look at the docs, Sequelize does support raw queries, but I think you should create a new question if you need further help.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/

Comment: Okay thank you so much for the help!! I'll look into it!

Comment: If you think that I've helped you find the right start, then feel free to mark this answer as correct.